# How do I target this with jQuery? (image)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to target the blue highlighted line in the image below and prepend a `<td>` to it.

[image]

I tried...

```
$('#wpf-wrapper .wpf:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(2)').prepend('<td class="emblem"></td>');
```

But it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: This would be much simpler if you could modify the DOM.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Are you sure? The folded sections lines should only show child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third child of `#wpf-wrapper` is not the third `.wpf`; it's `#trail`. Additionally, `:nth-child(2)` selects the second child, rather than the third.

Use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) instead:

```
$('#wpf-wrapper .wpf:eq(2) tr:nth-child(2)').prepend('<td class="emblem"></td>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:nth-child()` selector takes into account **all children**. Try using `:eq()` instead, which only counts from the result set of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wpf:eq(1) .forumsList tr:eq(1)").prepend('<td class="emblem"></td>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wpf-wrapper .wpf').eq(2).find('tr').eq(1).prepend('<td class="emblem"></td>');
```